# SpeedoJMXBean not exposed to JConsole

Tags: java, jmx

Consider the following program:

```
public class SpeedoJMXBean implements SpeedoListener {
private SpeedoDTO lastData;
private SpeedoBean speedo;

@Required
public void setSpeedo(SpeedoBean speedo) {
    this.speedo = speedo;
}

public void init() throws MBeanRegistrationException, InstanceAlreadyExistsException,      NotCompliantMBeanException, MalformedObjectNameException {
    speedo.addListener(this);
    MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName("MineStar:type=Speedometer,name=Statistics");
    MineStarMBean impl = new MineStarMBean();
    impl.addProperty(new PropertyAdapter("ThreadCount", "Thread Count", "java.lang.Integer") {
        public Object getValue() {
            return ThreadManagement.getThreadCount();
        }
    });
    impl.addProperty(new PropertyAdapter("Buffered", "Buffered Count", "java.lang.Integer") {
        public Object getValue() {
            if (lastData == null) return 0;
            return lastData.getBuffered();
        }
    });
    impl.addProperty(new PropertyAdapter("EPM", "Events Per Minute", "java.lang.Integer") {
        public Object getValue() {
            if (lastData == null) return 0;
            return lastData.getEventsPerMinute();
        }
    });
    server.registerMBean(impl, objectName);
}

@Override
public void speedoData(SpeedoDTO data) {
    lastData = data;
}

@Override
public void connectionPoolData(ConnectionPoolDTO data) {
    // not interested at the moment
}

@Override
public void gcActivity(GarbageCollectionDTO gcDTO) {
    // not interested at the moment
}
}
```

The SpeedoBean are not being exposed to the jconsole mbeans browser. I need to expose the Speedo information for my external tool. Can anyone tell me what is the problem here?

**NOTE- This is initialized in xml file as -**

```
<bean id="speedoJMX" class="com.mincom.env.service.server.gadget.SpeedoJMXBean" init-     method="init" scope="singleton"
      lazy-init="true">
    <property name="speedo">
        <ref local="speedo"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. As mentioned in this link [Click Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html) just changed lazy-init to false.

```
<bean id="speedoJMX" class="com.mincom.env.service.server.gadget.SpeedoJMXBean" init-     method="init" scope="singleton"
      lazy-init="false">
```